# Performance problem with query that is solved with a cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I got asked the question to find 5 people (pfileid) in our system that have a mobile phone number in our system and that have multiple files that can be of only one type (dfiletypeid). They also have to be a specific type of person on the file (pfiletypeid = 2).

I came up with this query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5
    y.PFileId,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pfilecommdescr FROM _PFileComm 
     WHERE PFileId = y.PFileId AND pfilecommtypeid = 2 
       AND LEN(pfilecommdescr) = 10 AND pfilecommdescr LIKE '04%') AS gsm,
    y.c AS c
FROM
    (SELECT
         x.pfileid,
         COUNT(*) AS c
     FROM
         (SELECT
              dflpf.pfileid,
              df.dfiletypeid,
              COUNT(*) AS c
          FROM 
              _dfile df
          JOIN
              _dfilelinkpfile dflpf ON df.dfileid = dflpf.dfileid 
                                    AND dflpf.pfiletypeid = 2
          GROUP BY
              dflpf.pfileid, df.dfiletypeid) x
     GROUP BY
         x.pfileid) y
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM _pfilecomm 
            WHERE pfileid = y.pfileid AND pfilecommtypeid = 2 
              AND LEN(pfilecommdescr) = 10 
              AND pfilecommdescr LIKE '04%')
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _dfilelinkpfile 
         WHERE pfileid = y.pfileid AND pfiletypeid = 2) > 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM _DFileLinkPFile 
                    WHERE PFileId = y.PFileId AND PFileTypeId <> 2)
    AND y.c = 1
```

I tried to run it for hours and I didn't get a result. I don't understand why it takes so long so I wrote a cursor instead:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'tblTemp_test')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE tblTemp_test (PFileId INT, GSM varchar(255), c INT)
END

DECLARE @PFileId BIGINT

DECLARE CheckPFileId CURSOR FOR SELECT PFileId FROM _PFile ORDER BY PFileId DESC

OPEN CheckPFileId

FETCH NEXT FROM CheckPFileId INTO @PFileId

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tblTemp_Axel_test) <> 5
BEGIN
    insert into dbo.tblTemp_Axel_test (PFileId, GSM, c)
    select
    y.PFileId,
    (select top 1 pfilecommdescr from _PFileComm where PFileId = y.PFileId and pfilecommtypeid = 2 and len(pfilecommdescr) = 10 and pfilecommdescr like '04%') as gsm,
    y.c as c
    from
        (
            select
            x.pfileid,
            count(*) as c
            from
                (
                    select
                    dflpf.pfileid,
                    df.dfiletypeid,
                    count(*) as c
                    from _dfile df
                    join _dfilelinkpfile dflpf on df.dfileid = dflpf.dfileid and     dflpf.pfiletypeid = 2
                    where dflpf.PFileId = @PFileId
                    group by dflpf.pfileid,df.dfiletypeid
                ) x
            group by x.pfileid
        ) y
    where exists (select 1 from _pfilecomm where pfileid = y.pfileid and pfilecommtypeid = 2 and len(pfilecommdescr) = 10 and pfilecommdescr like '04%')
    and (select count(*) from _dfilelinkpfile where pfileid = y.pfileid and pfiletypeid = 2) > 1
    and not exists (select 1 from _DFileLinkPFile where PFileId = y.PFileId and PFileTypeId <> 2)
    and y.c = 1
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM CheckPFileId INTO @PFileId
END

CLOSE CheckPFileId

DEALLOCATE CheckPFileId 

select * from dbo.tblTemp_test
```

It came up with the answer in seconds. Does anyone know why the first query can't give me a result in a similar time? I thought cursors were supposed to be the avoided at all costs in sql server for performance issues. It could be I didn't write the query optimally. I'm asking because I've had this problem before and I can't find an answer to it.

I tried to look in the estimated execution plan but it doesn't give me an answer to why it takes so long.

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Also your lack of column qualifying in your subqueries could be a bug in your code ([No, this is not a bug in T-SQL](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2019/04/23/no-this-is-not-a-bug-in-t-sql/)) which could be causing the wrong results.

Comment: *Why* would you remove the code and replace it with images... [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks Tom A., yes the ORDER BY I removed to try and make it run faster. In this example it didn't matter what 5 id's I found. Normally I'd always put an ORDER BY at the end. I removed to code and added images because the code was being presented in 1 line. I'm new to stackoverflow so I tried to make it as clear as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have changed in your query when wrapping it in cursor was adding a `WHERE` clause in the innermost query, so it must be the cause for the speedup.

I would assume that at least one of tables `_dfile`, `_dfilelinkpfile` stores a lot of data and that join you have used - `join _dfilelinkpfile dflpf on df.dfileid = dflpf.dfileid` - produces a very big result set.

Using cursor, you constrain that result set to records with currenly processed `PFileID`, which is probably a tiny subset of all records that your `JOIN` can return, which makes the whole query run fast. If there are a lot of people in your database that satisfy conditions you described, there is a high chance that Sql Server will only have to evaluate a few iterations of cursor, as opposed to computing the full joining result set and performing the whole query on it.

You can verify the above by:

- running your original query with additional `WHERE` clause, specifying a single ID - just like in your cursor (it will probably run fast);
- counting iterations in your cursor and storing the number somewhere (it will probably be much lower than number of distinct PFileIDs in your database).

That being said, **using a cursor here is still not a great idea** - the fact that it helped with performance only means that **your query is not written in optimal way** or that the optimizer cannot handle it correctly. For instance, there is some unneccessary aggregation in your query (COUNT(*) in the innermost query that you're never using).

It's impossible to test anything without your database structure, but I would try to simplify the query a bit:

```
SELECT TOP 5 PFileId, pcomm.PFileCommDescr, dflpf.FileCount
FROM _dfile df

-- only people having mobile phone number
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 PFileCommDescr 
    FROM _pfilecomm 
    WHERE PFileId = df.PFileId AND pfilecommtypeid = 2 
        AND LEN(pfilecommdescr) = 10 AND pfilecommdescr LIKE '04%'
) pcomm

-- only people who have more than one file with pfiletypeid = 2
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as FileCount
    FROM _dfilelinkpfile
    WHERE df.PFileId = PFileId AND pfiletypeid = 2
    GROUP BY PFileId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dflpf

-- only people whose all files have tha same dfiletypeid
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dfiletypeid) as DFileTypeCount
    FROM _dfilelinkpfile
    WHERE df.PFileId = PFileId
    GROUP BY PFileId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) dflpf_ntypes
```

Comment: I think that the last `CROSS APPLY` could be removed adding a condition to the previous `dflpf`, changing `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND MIN(dfiletypeid) = 2 AND MAX(dfiletypeid) = 2`.

Comment: @RobertoFerraris You're absolutly right - that's a good thing to do.